# How to use EZrgb24 filter

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

## Context

I'm trying to apply filter such as contrast, color change, brightness on every frame of a .avi video.

The video is playing just fine with directshow.net and c#.

after a couple hours of research, I found out that buffercb was not the way to go to do the job.

Apparantly, EZrgb24 is a filter I can add to my graph that does exactly what I want.

However, I can't get it to work.

## Added in the beggining of my class

```
[DllImport("ole32.dll", EntryPoint = "CoCreateInstance", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    static extern UInt32 CoCreateInstance([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid rclsid,
       IntPtr pUnkOuter, UInt32 dwClsContext, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid,
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object rReturnedComObject);
```

## Here is relevant code that works

```
        int hr = 0;

        IBaseFilter ibfRenderer = null;
        ISampleGrabber sampGrabber = null;
        IBaseFilter capFilter = null;
        IPin iPinInFilter = null;
        IPin iPinOutFilter = null;
        IPin iPinInDest = null;



        Type comType = null;
        object comObj = null;

        m_FilterGraph = new FilterGraph() as IFilterGraph2;

        try
        {
            // Get the SampleGrabber interface
            sampGrabber = new SampleGrabber() as ISampleGrabber;

            // Add the video source
            hr = m_FilterGraph.AddSourceFilter(_videoPath, "Ds.NET FileFilter", out capFilter);
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            // Hopefully this will be the video pin
            IPin iPinOutSource = DsFindPin.ByDirection(capFilter, PinDirection.Output, 0);

            IBaseFilter baseGrabFlt = sampGrabber as IBaseFilter;
            ConfigureSampleGrabber(sampGrabber);

            iPinInFilter = DsFindPin.ByDirection(baseGrabFlt, PinDirection.Input, 0);
            iPinOutFilter = DsFindPin.ByDirection(baseGrabFlt, PinDirection.Output, 0);

            // Add the frame grabber to the graph
            hr = m_FilterGraph.AddFilter(baseGrabFlt, "Ds.NET Grabber");
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            hr = m_FilterGraph.Connect(iPinOutSource, iPinInFilter);
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            // Get the default video renderer
            ibfRenderer = (IBaseFilter)new VideoRendererDefault();

            // Add it to the graph
            hr = m_FilterGraph.AddFilter(ibfRenderer, "Ds.NET VideoRendererDefault");
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
            iPinInDest = DsFindPin.ByDirection(ibfRenderer, PinDirection.Input, 0);

            // Connect the graph.  Many other filters automatically get added here
            hr = m_FilterGraph.Connect(iPinOutFilter, iPinInDest);
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);


            SaveSizeInfo(sampGrabber);

            HERE WE WANT TO ADD THE EZRGB FILTER.
```

## Code that doesnt work

```
            /*

            // { 8B498501-1218-11cf-ADC4-00A0D100041B }
            DEFINE_GUID(CLSID_EZrgb24,
            0x8b498501, 0x1218, 0x11cf, 0xad, 0xc4, 0x0, 0xa0, 0xd1, 0x0, 0x4, 0x1b);
             */
            unsafe
            {
                Guid IUnknownGuid = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"); //Can it be written in more pretty style?

                Guid ezrgbclsid = new Guid(0x8b498501, 0x1218, 0x11cf, 0xad, 0xc4, 0x0, 0xa0, 0xd1, 0x0, 0x4, 0x1b);
                uint hr1 = CoCreateInstance(ezrgbclsid, IntPtr.Zero, (uint)(CLSCTX.CLSCTX_INPROC_HANDLER), ezrgbclsid, out x);//CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER

                IIPEffect myEffect = (IIPEffect)x;// as IIPEffect;

                if (hr1 != 0)
                {
                    int iError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    Console.Write("CoCreateInstance Error = {0}, LastWin32Error = {1}", hr1, iError);

                }

                myEffect.put_IPEffect(1004, 0, 100); //for this filter, look at resource.h for what the int should be, in this case 1002 is the emboss effect

            }
```

## My diagnostic

I found out that the int value returned in hr1, is the hexadecimal value for dll not registred.
Which means to me that EZRGB is not registred on my computer.

## How I tryed to solve the problem

Found and downloaded EZRGB.ax on some obscure web site.

executed the command : 
    cd \windows\syswow64
    regsvr32 c:\ezrgb24.ax

A message box appeared with DllRegisterServer in c:\ezrgb24.ax succeeded.

Still doesn't work.

I am using directshow.net, however, this is also tagged both directshow as I feel the solution will work for either c# or c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use can use `SampleCB` instead of `BufferCB`; the former provides you access to data which is streamed further, so you can modify it
2. The typical problem with registration is that you build 32-bit DLL and you are trying to use it from 64-bit code. The bitnesses have to match.
3. You need `CLSCTX_ALL` or `CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Roman. 1) How is the SampleCB going to resolve my problem ? I though I was on the right track with adding a ezrgb24 filter on my graph ?  2) Interesting. it might be the problem. How can I solve it ? I am using vs 2012 C# and WPF

Comment: I builded my own strmbasd.lib, then builded my own ezrgb24.dll ( tryed 64 and 32 bit) , then in run -> regedit -> search my guid, and I find it with the description image filters, which is good. but in c#, I still get the error dll not registred.

Comment: `SampleCB` gets you real streamed data and `BufferCB` gives you a copy modifications on which are discarded.

Comment: I managed to get the dll to load in 32 bits. now I'm having trouble connecting it to my graph...

Comment: do you have tips or an example to connect my filter to my graph ? I can't find how to setup the pins. Also tryed to look it up in graphedit, but my filter is not in the options.

Comment: Update your code because it's unclear what you ended up with. Also in any event you are interested to understand what filter graph topology you have at the time of the problem.

Comment: okay, thanks, to be continued in a new question since I have a new problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813060/how-to-connect-ezrgb24-filter-to-my-graph