# How to connect EZrgb24 filter to my graph

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

## Context

I successfully loaded a 32 bit ezrgb24 COM   (compiled it from the samples)

The video is playing just fine with directshow.net and c#.

However, I dont know how to connect the ezrgb24 filter I created to my graph.

## Added in the beggining of my class

```
[ComImport,
System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity,
Guid("fd5010a3-8ebe-11ce-8183-00aa00577da1"), 
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]

public interface IIPEffect
{
    [PreserveSig]
    void get_IPEffect([Out] out int effectNum, [Out] out double StartTime, [Out] out double Length);

    [PreserveSig]
    void put_IPEffect([In] int effectNum, [In] double StartTime, [In] double Length);
}

internal enum CLSCTX
{
    Inproc = 0x03,
    Server = 0x15,
    All = 0x17,
}


[ComImport]
[Guid("8B498501-1218-11CF-ADC4-00A0D100041B")]
public class EZRGB24
{

}
```

## Relevant code

```
        IBaseFilter ibfRenderer = null;
        ISampleGrabber sampGrabber = null;
        IBaseFilter capFilter = null;
        IPin iPinInFilter = null;
        IPin iPinOutFilter = null;
        IPin iPinInDest = null;



        Type comType = null;
        object comObj = null;

        m_FilterGraph = new FilterGraph() as IFilterGraph2;

        try
        {
            // Get the SampleGrabber interface
            sampGrabber = new SampleGrabber() as ISampleGrabber;

            // Add the video source
            hr = m_FilterGraph.AddSourceFilter(_videoPath, "Ds.NET FileFilter", out capFilter);
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            // Hopefully this will be the video pin
            IPin iPinOutSource = DsFindPin.ByDirection(capFilter, PinDirection.Output, 0);

            IBaseFilter baseGrabFlt = sampGrabber as IBaseFilter;
            ConfigureSampleGrabber(sampGrabber);

            iPinInFilter = DsFindPin.ByDirection(baseGrabFlt, PinDirection.Input, 0);
            iPinOutFilter = DsFindPin.ByDirection(baseGrabFlt, PinDirection.Output, 0);

            // Add the frame grabber to the graph
            hr = m_FilterGraph.AddFilter(baseGrabFlt, "Ds.NET Grabber");
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            hr = m_FilterGraph.Connect(iPinOutSource, iPinInFilter);
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            // Get the default video renderer
            ibfRenderer = (IBaseFilter)new VideoRendererDefault();

            // Add it to the graph
            hr = m_FilterGraph.AddFilter(ibfRenderer, "Ds.NET VideoRendererDefault");
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
            iPinInDest = DsFindPin.ByDirection(ibfRenderer, PinDirection.Input, 0);

            // Connect the graph.  Many other filters automatically get added here
            hr = m_FilterGraph.Connect(iPinOutFilter, iPinInDest);
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);


            SaveSizeInfo(sampGrabber);


            ----- everything works fine up to here.

            IIPEffect myClass = (IIPEffect)(new EZRGB24());


            myClass.put_IPEffect(1008, 0, 100000);


            hr = m_FilterGraph.AddFilter((IBaseFilter)myClass, "EZRGB24");

            IPin inPinx = DsFindPin.ByDirection((IBaseFilter)myClass, PinDirection.Input, 0);
            m_FilterGraph.Connect(iPinOutSource, inPinx);

            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
```

When I mouse over myClass, I can see it's not null.

Also, I tryed to plug onto my graph with graph edit, but my program isn't listed. 
Also, hr is 0 after that line
      hr = m_FilterGraph.AddFilter((IBaseFilter)myClass, "EZRGB24");

I am using directshow.net, however, this is also tagged both directshow as I feel the solution will work for either c# or c++.

This is a follow up of my previous question [How to use EZrgb24 filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797025/how-to-use-ezrgb24-filter)

Comment: You need to read on adding graph to ROT for inspection with external tool. You need to understand what graph you have, since it might be different from what you expect. You might want to use [DirectShowSpy](http://alax.info/blog/1460) + GraphEdit/[GraphStudioNext](https://code.google.com/p/graph-studio-next/) as troubleshooting tools. Pop up a message box from your code at specific points, and inspect the graphs to see what you are getting.

Comment: @RomanR. Thanks Roman, I will install these tools. But the question remains, how do you connect a filter to the graph. There is literally no example of that.

Comment: The methods in your code snippet are about right: `AddFilter`, `Connect`. I don't see any need to guess what goes wrong since there is too little information, and powerful tools are not yet used against the problem.

Comment: @RomanR. Thanks for the reply. Yeah I'm pretty sure I'm using the right methods but what parameters to use for the Connect fonction ?  What are the pins to use ?

Comment: You connect pins you want to connect. With GraphEdit you have a pretty straightforward visualization of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `iPinOutSource` twice to connect. First you execute:

```
// Hopefully this will be the video pin
IPin iPinOutSource = DsFindPin.ByDirection(capFilter, PinDirection.Output, 0);

hr = m_FilterGraph.Connect(iPinOutSource, iPinInFilter);
```

and later

```
m_FilterGraph.Connect(iPinOutSource, inPinx);
```

A pin can only have one connection.

Comment: Makes sense. How do I figure the pins to use ? I can't get graph edit to work. It crashes when I connect to my remote graph, and also I can't see the rgb24 filter in the menu. both ezrgb24 and proppage 32 and 64 are registred

Comment: Are you able to create the graph you want when you use graphedit standalone? Basicly when you want to include a extra filter C in a graph between filter A and B, you should not connect A to B, but A to C and then C to B. Always connect from the beginning to the end, that avoids some problems.

Comment: Ok thanks. Yes I can create a graph, but as I said, I can't see the ezrgb24 filter

Comment: I ended up getting graph edit plus to work by messing around with different proppage.dlls. Once I got that to work, I easily figured the pins etc. Basically, I had to add another filter between the ezrgb and the VideoRendererDefault one.